# Make a union of two Joda-Time Interval objects

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime

In [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), is there any way to create a [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) as a union of two other intervals. I know there is intersection method which is called [`overlap`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html#overlap%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29) (and [overlaps](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#overlaps%28org.joda.time.ReadableInterval%29)). But I can not see any union methods.

Comment: What is a "union" of two time intervals?  If they're contiguous (one starts at the exact instant the other one ends) you might be able to join them, but if they're not they're just two time intervals.  what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: As @JimGarrison said, you cannot expect to union every pair of intervals. If there is a gap then you need an extra type to represent a collection of non-contiguous intervals. This type does not exist in JodaTime, also no corresponding union-method which delivers an array or a collection or similar.

Comment: I am just trying to get interval that includes both

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want an interval that "covers" two others, just create a new interval that runs from `min(a.start, b.start)` to `max(a.end, b.end)`.

If you need to represent the gap as well, then you'll need to write your own classes to handle the behavior you want. There's nothing builtin to Joda-time for this as there are several possible interpretations of what it means to "union" non-contiguous intervals.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20806235/642706) is correct, but brief. I decided to try an implementation. Using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 with Java 7 on a Mac.

If you made much use of this kind of "union" method, perhaps you should consider creating a subclass of `Interval` to add a method where you pass a single (second) Interval to be compared to the first, the one whose method is being called.

For occasional use, a static method stuck away on some utility class would suffice. That's what I wrote here, a static method where you pass a pair of Intervals. A new Interval is returned.

Rather than use multiple-line `if` statements, my example code uses the [`?:` ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) to collapse to one line the decision to pull the first or second [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

Static method…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.

static Interval union( Interval firstInterval, Interval secondInterval ) 
{
    // Purpose: Produce a new Interval instance from the outer limits of any pair of Intervals.

    // Take the earliest of both starting date-times.
    DateTime start =  firstInterval.getStart().isBefore( secondInterval.getStart() )  ? firstInterval.getStart() : secondInterval.getStart();
    // Take the latest of both ending date-times.
    DateTime end =  firstInterval.getEnd().isAfter( secondInterval.getEnd() )  ? firstInterval.getEnd() : secondInterval.getEnd();
    // Instantiate a new Interval from the pair of DateTime instances.
    Interval unionInterval = new Interval( start, end );

    return unionInterval;
}
```

Example usage…

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

// Note the various time zones.
Interval i1 = new Interval( new DateTime( 2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) );
Interval i2 = new Interval( new DateTime( 2013, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ), new DateTime( 2013, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ) );

Interval i3 = TimeExample.union( i1, i2 );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println("i1: " + i1 );
System.out.println("i2: " + i2 );
// Note that Joda-Time adjusts the ending DateTime's time zone to match the starting one.
System.out.println("i3: " + i3 );
```

When run…

```
i1: 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00/2013-01-04T18:00:00.000-05:00
i2: 2013-01-10T00:00:00.000+01:00/2013-01-15T00:00:00.000+01:00
i3: 2013-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00/2013-01-14T18:00:00.000-05:00
```